# find multiple different strings and replace them

Tags: macos, file, ubuntu, terminal, find-replace

How can I find multiple different strings in a file and replace them all with the same string?

For example, I have a file that looks like this:

```
.revicon-search-1:before
.revicon-pencil-1:before
.revicon-picture-1:before
```

I fould like to find `.revicon-picture-1:before` and `.revicon-search-1:before` and replace it with `SOMETHING`. The number of strings I would like to replace is 100-1000.

How can I achieve this? I am on mac.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/20414/find-and-replace-text-within-a-file-using-commands

Comment: `sed -i 's/original/new/g' file.txt`